# Angular route: URL like /my/:parameter/path

Tags: angular, url-parameters, angular-router, angular7

I am trying to setup a URL like `'user/:id/edit'`, but when I use `[routerLink]="['user/:id/edit', 1]"` it generates `/user/:id/edit/1`.

If I use `[routerLink]="['user/:id/edit', {id: 1}]"` it generates `/user/:id/edit;id=1`

Is there a way of getting the output as `/users/1/edit` without using String  interpolation?

Comment: you can also use: *`router.navigate(['your_url']);`*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this question of yours is an extension of [another question of yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614857/is-there-a-way-to-name-a-route-in-angular-7/53615432#53615432)
Here your requirement would be to get an array which is correctly translated with respect to the parameters you want to pass. With this what I mean is:

Let's say we have a route configuration as

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "first/:id1/second/:id2", component: HelloComponent}
]
```

When using this in a `[routerLink]`, you will want to have the input property to be like: `['first', 'param1', 'second', 'param2']`. Not as: `['first/param1/second/param2']`. If you do this then even though you will be routed to the desired path, your `ActivatedRoute` will not have any params inside them(in case you need to grab the params from the router).

Now your task would be to create such array for the `routerLinks`.

Let's create a `Pipe` which does this and is performance efficient.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'routerArray'
})
export class RouterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(routerPath: string, params: string | number[]): string | number[] {
        // regex to find all the param placeholders in the route path
        let regex = /(\/:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/?)/g;
        // will be returned as output
        let routerArray = [];
        // contains the output of regex.exec()
        let match = null;
        // index to retrieve the parameters for route from params array
        let paramIndex = 0;
        while (match = regex.exec(routerPath)) {
            // push the first part of the path with param placeholder
            routerArray.push(routerPath.substring(0, match.index))
            // push the param at paramIndex
            routerArray.push(params[paramIndex++]);
            // remove the contents from routerPath which are processed
            routerPath = routerPath.substring(regex.lastIndex);
            // regex is stateful, reset the lastIndex coz routerPath was changed.
            regex.lastIndex = 0;
        }
        // if the recieved route path didn't accept any argumets
        if (routerArray.length === 0) {
            routerArray.push(routerPath)
        }
        return routerArray
    }
}
```

Now you can use the pipe like:

```
<button [routerLink]="'first/:id1/second/:id2' | routerArray: ['1', '2']">Click to Navigate</button>
```

See an [Example here...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-names?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: that is exactly what I did. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this : `[routerLink]="['/user/', 1, '/edit']"`

More generally, you can put your id parameter like this :

`[routerLink]="['/user', <your param 1>, 'edit', <your param 2>]"`

Comment: this will do, although I'm not sure if edit should be '/edit' or just 'edit'

Answer (score 0):

In component, you can do this with [`Router`](https://angular.io/guide/router):

Imports:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){
}

navigate(id){
this.router.navigate(['/user/'+id+'/edit']);
}
```